# Conditional issue in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I don't understand why my conditional isn't working. I just keep returning `myVar = 1` for both intervals,

```
var myVar;

$(window).scroll(function() {


 if($(window).width() >= 1440) {
    myVar = 2
   }


 if($(window).width() >= 1024 &&  $(window).width() < 1440) {
    myVar = 1
   }

 })
```

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: I receive `myVar = 1` in both intervals that I created

Comment: Is your window actually over 2000px wide?

Comment: Your code is missing a closing paren. Is this a typo?

Comment: You were right, but I still got the problem

Comment: How scrolling a window can change it size ?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  var myVar = -1;

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    console.log($(window).width());
    if ($(window).width() >= 1440) {
      myVar = 2;
    } else if ($(window).width() >= 1024 && $(window).width() < 1440) {
      myVar = 1;
    }
    console.log(myVar);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height: 4000px; width: 2000px;">
</div>
```

If you expand the snippet, it will work better. I was seeing about 689 when testing otherwise.

Did you you mean `$(window).scrollTop()` to see how far down the page the User has gone?